# Using Windows network path with python

Tags: python, windows, shared-directory

Is possible to use windows network path with python functions?

ex. `//SERVERNAME/SharedFolder`

For example something like `os.makedirs('////SERVERNAME//SharedFolder//NewFolder')`

It seems it doesn't work for me

Thanks,
Federico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using raw string.

**Ex:**

```
os.makedirs(r'\\SERVERNAME\SharedFolder\NewFolder')
```

Comment: I tried but i get: [Errno 20047] Unknown error: 20047: '\\\\'

Comment: Strange the above line works fine for me. Do you have `r` in front of you path?